# Unable to view in-memory table from SQLite database in PyCharm

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

I am using PyCharm to capture some data from web and push it into in-memory database-table on SQLite. I have debugged the code, it works fine, in the debugger I can see data being fetched, it being pushed into db[table] location.

Python code is as below -

```
import requests
import dataset
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

def begin():
    db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///quotes.db')
    authors_seen = set()
    base_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'

def clean_url(url):
    # Clean '/author/Steve-Martin' to 'Steve-Martin'
    # Use urljoin to make an absolute URL
    url = urljoin(base_url, url)
    # Use urlparse to get out the path part
    path = urlparse(url).path
    # Now split the path by '/' and get the second part
    # E.g. '/author/Steve-Martinvisual studio' -> ['','author', 'Steve-Martin']
    return path.split('/')[2]

def scrape_quotes(html_soup):
    for quote in html_soup.select('div.quote'):
        quote_text = quote.find(class_='text').get_text(strip=True)
        quote_author_url = clean_url(quote.find(class_='author').find_next_sibling('a').get('href'))
        quote_tag_urls = [clean_url(a.get('href')) for a in quote.find_all('a', class_='tag')]
        authors_seen.add(quote_author_url)
        # Store this quote and its tags
        quote_id = db['quotes'].insert({'text' : quote_text, 'author' : quote_author_url})
        db['quotes_tags'].insert_many([{'quote_id' : quote_id, 'tag_id' : tag} for tag in quote_tag_urls])

def scrape_author(html_soup, author_id):
    author_name = html_soup.find(class_='author-title').get_text(strip=True)
    author_born_date = html_soup.find(class_='author-born-date').get_text(strip=True)
    author_born_loc = html_soup.find(class_='author-born-location').get_text(strip=True)
    author_desc = html_soup.find(class_='author-description').get_text(strip=True)
    db['authors'].insert({'author_id': author_id, 'name': author_name,
                          'born_date': author_born_date, 'born_location': author_born_loc,
                          'description': author_desc})

# Start by scraping all the quote pages
print('*****Beginning scraping process - quotes first.*****')
url = base_url
while True:
    print('Now scraping page:', url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    # Scrape the quotes
    scrape_quotes(html_soup)
    # Is there a next page?
    next_a = html_soup.select('li.next > a')
    if not next_a or not next_a[0].get('href'):
        break
    url = urljoin(url, next_a[0].get('href'))
# Now fetch out the author information
print('*****Scraping authors data.*****')
for author_id in authors_seen:
    url = urljoin(base_url, '/author/' + author_id)
    print('Now scraping author:', url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    # Scrape the author information
    scrape_author(html_soup, author_id)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

What I am struggling with is the pycharm IDE connection. As shown in the figure below, I can see quotes.sqlite database. It has only one table listed - sqlite_master. Under server objects there are collations, modules and routines, which is part of infrastructure provided by SQLite.

[image: SQLite connection view]

Also, when I view the db object (python's driver to SQLite) in debugger, I can see the relevant table as shown in the picture below -

[image: Debugger showing tables]

Any ideas why PyCharm refuses to show relevant table/collection in the IDE?